# Can't get MariaDB docker to work without password

Tags: mariadb, docker, password

I want to add MariaDB to my docker compose file, like this:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    mariadb:
        image: 'mariadb:10.3'
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - "${PWD}/data/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'rootpass'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
            MYSQL_USER: 'dev'
```

Now I can connect using `-uroot -p` and entering the `rootpass` password, but I can't connect using `-udev` and no password. It says:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'dev'@'172.31.0.1' (using password: NO)
```

I also tried adding `MYSQL_PASSWORD: ~` or `MYSQL_PASSWORD: ''` to the environment variables, but that also doesn't work.

It works when I add an actual password `MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'dev'`, but I can't get it working without password. Does anyone know the magic combination of env vars?

The reason I want to achieve this, is because my team has this set up currently in a different way and everyone has a `.my.cnf` file containing `user=dev` and `password=`. So it would be nice if everyone could keep this local config unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from the [entrypoint](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/master/10.3/docker-entrypoint.sh#L350) is:

```
    if  [ -n "$MARIADB_PASSWORD" ] || [ -n "$MARIADB_PASSWORD_HASH" ] && [ -n "$MARIADB_USER" ]; then
        mysql_note "Creating user ${MARIADB_USER}"
        if [ -n "$MARIADB_PASSWORD_HASH" ]; then
            createUser="CREATE USER '$MARIADB_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '$MARIADB_PASSWORD_HASH';"
        else
            # SQL escape the user password, \ followed by '
            local userPasswordEscaped
            userPasswordEscaped=$( docker_sql_escape_string_literal "${MARIADB_PASSWORD}" )
            createUser="CREATE USER '$MARIADB_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$userPasswordEscaped';"
        fi

        if [ -n "$MARIADB_DATABASE" ]; then
            mysql_note "Giving user ${MARIADB_USER} access to schema ${MARIADB_DATABASE}"
            userGrants="GRANT ALL ON \`${MARIADB_DATABASE//_/\\_}\`.* TO '$MARIADB_USER'@'%';"
        fi
    fi
```

So the `MARIADB_PASSWORD` (and the old `MYSQL_PASSWORD` that gets copied to `MARIADB_PASSWORD`) must not be empty for it to create a user.

`MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD` (aka `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD`) only ever applied to the root password hence the [name change](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/blob/master/10.3/docker-entrypoint.sh#L225).

One way is to use the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` to have a `reset_pass.sql` file:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR dev@`%` = PASSWORD('')
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing it up. So it is either having this initial SQL file in every project, or just stop using an empty password/no password :D